# Is it possible to go back to the Slums after story finished?

Tags: dying-light

As the title says i want to know if it's possible to travel between the slums and the old town after i've completed the Story. Second question for this - is it possible to travel back to slums while the story is in the old town, if yes, is there a fast-travel way available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you have been to both the Slums and Old Town, you can fast travel between them. You do so using posters in the main safe houses (the towers). Below are the photos of the map icons and the posters. You can fast travel between them even after you have beaten the main mission.

[image: Slums Fast Travel]
[image]
[image: Old Town Fast Travel]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, it will be possible to do the same after story i guess. Would make no sense to me if you could not keep smashing the braindeads

Comment: Finished the game. You are able to fast travel after you complete all the main missions. I will update my answer.

Comment: Same here just finished 2days ago just forgot to add this in comments xD

Answer (score 1):

Go to either tower/base, slums by the merchant on the 1st floor or old town also by the merchant and click the poster hanging to warp between